# Editting/deleting multiple tables in 1 java jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, edit

Currently I got the following code:

```
<%@page language="java"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<form method="post" action="update.jsp">
<table border="1">
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Genre</th><th>Site</th></tr>
<%
String num = request.getParameter("id");
int id = Integer.parseInt(num);
try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("sample connection", "sample user", "sample pass");
String query = "select * from table where id='"+id+"'";
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()){
%>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="id" value="<%=rs.getInt("id")%>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="naam" value="<%=rs.getString("name")%>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Genre" value="<%=rs.getString("genre")%>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="url" value="<%=rs.getString("url")%>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update" style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;"></td>
</tr>
<%
}
}
catch(Exception e){}
%>
</table>
</form>
```

Basically this is the jsp page to update 1 table of my database, however is it possible to make a general jsp page for any table (different amount of columns, different column names etc) or do you have to create a specific jsp page for every single table you have? Also if it's possible, how would you do it and what would I need?
Cause honestly, I have no idea how to start with that.

I assume that if it's possible for an edit, that it's also possible for a delete and insert. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a controller with required methods to process a request to crud each table and make either a jsp page with all tables or a number of pages for every single table.

if you could split the view and logic it would make the development process a way more easy and flexible